# Dialogflow webhook set parameter value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, dialogflow-es, chatbot

My intent sends a webhook as part of slot filling if a parameter is missing from the user query. My webhook then uses logic to estimate the value of the parameter. How can I return this parameter as part of the WebhookResponse object? I am using the C# client library in an ASP.NET Core app.

My code is:

```
string fulfillmentText;
WebhookRequest request = null;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
{
    request = jsonParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(reader);
}
//If Parameter-1 has no value
if (request.QueryResult.Fields["Parameter-1].StringValue.Length == 0)
{
    fulfillmentText = "I have guessed the value of Parameter-1";
    //I apply some logic that is unimportant to this question
    //For the sake of simplicity, say I estimate the value of Parameter-1 to be "foobar"
    //I want to be able to give the parameter this value like this:
    parameter["Parameter-1"] = "foobar"

}
```

**UPDATE**

So, I have pretty much got it all working using Prisoner's method. I will retry sid8491's at some point too. My intent is trying to obtain a user's address. I have required custom entities to retrieve the street number, street name, suburb and state.

[image]

Without creating any contexts myself, the following context is automatically generated by Dialogflow: `projects/telebot-pianomoves-v1/agent/sessions/2b42cbc8-2418-4231-e4c0-bd3a175f2ea8/contexts/1320fe35-4329-4176-b136-9221dfaddd4e_id_dialog_context`. I receive this context in my webhook, and can then CHANGE the value of a parameter. Let's assume $Suburb_Entity had no value in the webhook request and my code then returned the above context with the a new value for `Suburb_Entity`. My code successfully changes the `Suburb_Entity` from `""` to `aspendale` as can be seen by the webhook response json:

[image]

Now the odd thing is, although I changed the `Suburb_Entity` to an actual value in the `outputContext` of my webhook response, the actual parameter `$Suburb_Entity` only changes to the new value of `Suburb_Entity` from the outputContext on the NEXT detect intent request. So, keeping in mind the fact that I returned the new `Suburb_Entity` in the `outputContext` of the webhook response, this is the detect intent response I get - noting that $Suburb_Entity is yet to be changed:

[image]

On the next detect intent request, the webhook request parameter `Suburb_Entity` is set to `aspendale` and `$Suburb_Entity` also equals `aspendale`. The important thing about this, is `$Suburb_Entity` only changed to the outputContext parameter value on the NEXT detect intent request, of which would have triggered another webhook. `$Suburb_Entity` did not change during the same detect intent request as when I modified the `outputContext` parameter `Suburb_Entity`, but in the next. This leads me to believe that somehow, `$Suburb_Entity` inherits parameter values from this automatically generated context. The issue here, is that when my webhook responds with the `outputContext` paramter `Suburb_Entity` equalling `aspendale`, `$Suburb_Entity` does not change to this value until the next request. This means that if all the other parameters have values set, but `$Suburb_Entity` is yet to have changed value, then `allRequiredParamsSet == false`. If I return the `Suburb_Entity` in the `outputContext`, I want it to immediately change the value of `$Suburb_Entity` without requiring another detect intent request so that `allRequiredParamsSet == true` in such a circumstance. I tried setting the default value by doing this (it didn't work):

[image]

An alternative of course would be a way for me to force `allRequiredParamsSet = true`. I save the parameter values from this the context parameter, not the actual response. So I don't *need* `$Suburb_Entity`, I just want the intent to think that it has a value.

Cheers

Comment: please explain in details with screenshot of intent and possibly more webhook code.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

When you use a webhook for "slot filling", the intention is that you return the prompts you want to ask the user for and continue to use the same Intent to handle the responses. You're not expected to create values yourself.

If you want to "fill in" some answers that are used in the static "response" section of the Dialogflow Intent, or if you just want to record the answers so you can use them later, you can set the parameters of a Context. In the response string, you can refer to this value as `#context-name.parameter-name`.

**Update**

I don't know the internal mechanics of slot filling, but it doesn't surprise me that setting a value in the internal context for the input parameters doesn't "register" until the next round of handling the Intent.

The webhook for slot filling isn't intended to create values - it is intended to handle values and create *prompts* for the user to respond to. Intents are generally about processing user inputs and webhooks about handling them.

My workaround suggested that if you want this for output, you use the context for output.

Comment: sir, this time, i chose to post my answer even though you already posted :)

Comment: No worries! Multiple answers are always fine - one may help a person with a question more than another.

Comment: If I understand what you’re saying correctly, I set an “output-context” in the webhook response? How do I do this and maintain state?

Comment: If I understand what you’re saying correctly, I set an “output-context” in the webhook response? Will this just add a context variable and not affect state?

Comment: Correct, this ads a context parameter (which is part of the state), but does not change the user-provided information.

Comment: I am getting the error `WebhookResponse.OutputContexts cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`, what do I do about this?

Comment: Can you create a new StackOverflow question showing how you're trying to set the OutputContexts and exactly the error you're getting?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559839/setting-output-contexts-in-dialogflow. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have modified the question. Your approach works fantastically except for one part - which I described in the update. I have been stuck on trying to resolve this one issue for several hours now and I was hoping you might have an idea for fixing it. Sorry for the convoluted update but it's a weird problem to describe and I thought images would help :)

Comment: the images helped, although I'm not sure the answer will help you much.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple steps for get it done:

1. First give an event in intent
2. Check your condition in webhook
3. If your condition is satisfied, invoke the intent by calling the event from webhook which you have defined in step 1
4. Pass the paylaod (in json format) along with event calling, give parameters in the payload
5. In the intent, give default value of parameter as `#eventName.parameterName`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did work, but seemed to add around 2000ms extra delay before I received the fulfillment text.

Comment: @HarryStuart umm it did not happen in my case, after all it is passing the parameter value, invoking the same intent again and giving the response.

Comment: Is this possible by using output contexts instead of events i.e. set output context based on fulfillment and give default value to parameter as #output-context.parameter-name. I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @user75252 yes, you can do it. check the answer below by Prisoner

Comment: @user75252 i think using context is more useful.