# Setting output contexts in Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, dialogflow-es

Using the C# client library for Dialogflow, I am trying to set the output context in a webhook response. However, the output context field is read only. This is my code:

```
WebhookResponse response = new WebhookResponse
   {
       FulfillmentText = "This is a test",
       OutputContexts = ... //Regardless of what I try and set OutputContexts to be, I get the error "property or indexer 'WebhookResponse.OutputContexts' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"
   };
```

How do I set the output context?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The C# Client Library isn't for webhooks, it is for calling Dialogflow from a separate program. If you're trying to use C# in a webhook, you don't want to use the "Client Library". If I'm misunderstanding - can you update to include which library you're using specifically?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but just in case someone has the same problem.

You can not assign a new list to OutputContexts, you have to add them to the list:

For example:

```
response.OutputContexts.Add(new Context
            {
                Name = $"{request.Session}/your_context",
                LifespanCount = 1
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `response json` which you are forming is wrong.
Below is the correct json response which you need to send:

```
{
    "fulfillmentText = "This is a test",
    "outputContexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects/project_id/agent/sessions/session_id/contexts/your_context",
            "lifespanCount": 5,
            "parameters": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "foo1": "bar1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "followupEventInput": {
        "name": "even_name"
    }
}
```